# How to get the whole HTML source code from some website in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I spent whole day to find a Qt code to get a source code from some website(e.g. www.google.com), but everything I found, it didn't work. So, please can someone post the code how to get the source code from website? (I am using Qt creator and I don't know nothing about slot connecting, so please write the code without the slot connecting(or whatever is this) if it is even possible.

EDIT: Here is the code:

project.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2011-01-02T21:40:52
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui
QT       += webkit network

TARGET = facebook
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->buttonBack->setText("");                                           /*******************************/
    ui->buttonForward->setText("");                                        /*       Clear text from       */
    ui->buttonReload->setText("");                                         /*         the buttons         */
    ui->buttonStop->setText("");                                           /*******************************/
    ui->buttonBack->setIcon( QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_ArrowBack));            /*******************************/
    ui->buttonForward->setIcon( QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_ArrowForward));      /*         Set an icons        */
    ui->buttonReload->setIcon( QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_BrowserReload));      /*        on the buttons       */
    ui->buttonStop->setIcon( QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_BrowserStop));          /*******************************/
    //QString htmlOfPage;
    /********    T    E    S    T    ********/

    //ui->browser->setHtml("<html><body>Test</body></html>");

    /********    T    E    S    T    ********/
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_buttonBack_clicked()
{
    ui->browser->back();
}

void MainWindow::on_buttonForward_clicked()
{
    ui->browser->forward();
}

void MainWindow::on_buttonReload_clicked()
{
    ui->browser->reload();
}

void MainWindow::on_buttonStop_clicked()
{
    ui->browser->stop();
}

void MainWindow::on_browser_loadFinished(bool )
{
    //QWebView webview;
    //webview.setUrl (QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
    //QString s =  webview.page()->mainFrame()->toHtml();
    //htmlOfPage = ui->browser.page()->mainFrame()->toHtml();
}
```

I have a file mainwindow.h and mainwindow.ui too, but I think that nobody needs those files, so I didn't post them.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QUrl>


class MyClass : public QObject{

    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void onFinished() {
        QIODevice * content = static_cast<QIODevice*>(QObject::sender());
        qDebug() << content->readAll();
        content->deleteLater();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QNetworkAccessManager nam;
    MyClass obj;

    QNetworkReply * reply = nam.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://google.com")));
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &obj, SLOT(onFinished()));

    app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Won't work unless he adds `QT += network` to the project pro file.

Comment: Where to put this code? .. I added my code to the question, so you can easly tell me where to put the code. :)